# Why doesn't Ubuntu see all the memory I have installed?

Tags: memory, ram

How can this be:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t memory
[sudo] password for dims:
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM0
        Bank Connections: 0 1
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: DIMM SDRAM
        Installed Size: 2048 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Enabled Size: 2048 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM1
        Bank Connections: 2 3
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: DIMM SDRAM
        Installed Size: 4096 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Enabled Size: 4096 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Error Status: OK

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM2
        Bank Connections: 4 5
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: DIMM SDRAM
        Installed Size: 2048 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Enabled Size: 2048 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Error Status: OK

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM3
        Bank Connections: 6 7
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: DIMM SDRAM
        Installed Size: 4096 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Enabled Size: 4096 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0030
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 2048 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM0
        Bank Locator: BANK0
        Type: DDR
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1333 MHz
        Manufacturer: Manufacturer0
        Serial Number: SerNum0
        Asset Tag: AssetTagNum0
        Part Number: PartNum0
        Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0030
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM1
        Bank Locator: BANK1
        Type: DDR
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1333 MHz
        Manufacturer: Manufacturer1
        Serial Number: SerNum1
        Asset Tag: AssetTagNum1
        Part Number: PartNum1
        Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x0036, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0030
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 2048 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM2
        Bank Locator: BANK2
        Type: DDR
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1333 MHz
        Manufacturer: Manufacturer2
        Serial Number: SerNum2
        Asset Tag: AssetTagNum2
        Part Number: PartNum2
        Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x0038, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0030
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 4096 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM3
        Bank Locator: BANK3
        Type: DDR
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1333 MHz
        Manufacturer: Manufacturer3
        Serial Number: SerNum3
        Asset Tag: AssetTagNum3
        Part Number: PartNum3
        Rank: Unknown

$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       6102336    5605508     496828      31384     769868    3664868
-/+ buffers/cache:    1170772    4931564
Swap:      6282236     103584    6178652
```

Looks like `free` only sees `6G`, while there are `12` installed. Why?

**UPDATE**

Some output from the top of `dmesg`:

```
[    0.000000] reg 0, base: 0GB, range: 4GB, type WB
[    0.000000] reg 1, base: 4GB, range: 2GB, type WB
[    0.000000] reg 2, base: 6GB, range: 512MB, type WB
[    0.000000] reg 3, base: 3584MB, range: 512MB, type UC
[    0.000000] total RAM covered: 6144M
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G   12K  2.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           596M   21M  576M   4% /run
/dev/sda1       288G   29G  245G  11% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            3.0G  148K  3.0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user
```

**UPDATE 3**

Motherboard is [Asus P7P55-M](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7P55M/), physical look of memory sockets is

[image]

picture from manual is following

[image]

I have 2 DIMMs 2G each and 2 DIMMs 4G each, and I am plugging them in each color by size.

Comment: I assume the output of dmidecode is correct, right? You actually have 4 physical RAM sticks? Because it looks as though it's reporting each one twice. Can you show us the full `dmidecode` output?

Comment: See my update please. I was wishing not to climb on to the shelf and check physical sticks. I have information on paper, that I have 4 sticks 4+2+4+2 which corresponds to `dmidecode` info.

Comment: How much, if any, of your RAM is dedicated to `/dev/shm`?

Comment: Does `journalctl | grep -i "memory.*available"` also show 6GB?

Comment: Could you check the top part of dmesg?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick no `journalctl` program and not package with such name.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi see my update please

Comment: Check the documentation for whatever motherboard you have to see if it's using mirrored memory.

Comment: The reg 3 is suspect. Check with BIOS manual about supported RAM, and where you should install them (there are usually some rules to put memory with same size in specific slots). Or try to swap the middle banks. Check BIOS settings [did you changed/optimized the memory settings, for an old memory settings]. Did you reserve some memory for other stuffs [video, or external hardware]? Save the BIOS to a file and reset it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick can I check this programmatically?